# PHP memory limit is not changing in nginx. Changed /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini and /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

Tags: php, nginx

I am having ubuntu server installed nginx and php.

When we try to change the memory limit in php ini in the below path, it is not affecting php info.

I changed both ini files here is the path  /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini and /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

Please see the attached screenshots

[php info page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez9RQ.png)

[image]

[image: php ini screenshot]

Please help me where to change php settings, so that it will reflect in my server.

Comment: Did you restart the FPM process after?

Comment: yes. Restarted, sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm

Comment: are you sure nginx use your FPM php ?

Comment: Yes. Please check this screenshot link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez9RQ.png

Comment: OP, did you ever figure this out? Because mine won't reflect my increased memory_limit either.

Answer (score 0):

Check the php-fpm pool configuration file (in my case /etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.d/www.conf) for any directive forcing php parameters, for example php_admin_value[memory_limit].

In my case php.ini memory_limit parameter was ignored and instead of this was used the memory_limit defined into the php-fpm pool.